# Display images with Thymeleaf - Spring Boot

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I cannot display an image using *Thymeleafand* Spring Boot, this is my folder structure:

[image]

An this is the html and thymeleaf code:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="../static/images/photo.png" th:src="@{/resources/static/images/photo.png}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing to

```html
<img class="img-responsive" src="../static/images/photo.png" th:src="@{images/photo.png}" />
```